# Why won't my code get to a particular else block?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

This simple validation issue is driving me a little insane! I'm comparing it to a heap of other examples I've been learning with and I just can't get it...

I'm trying to have the program return the simple message "Please complete all fields." if the user leaves any field blank when submitting. It never gets to that code. I've got other similar examples where it does, so it must be something really simple I'm missing. Can anyone advise me why I'm not getting to that 'else' statement after the 'if (!empty...) block?

```
<?php

//PHPAcademy.org Tutorial on PDO

$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      =>  'localhost',
    'username'  =>  'root',
    'password'  =>  'andrew',
    'dbname'    =>  'a_database'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);

if (isset($_POST['food']) && isset($_POST['calories']) && isset($_POST['healthy_unhealthy'])) {
    $food = $_POST['food'];
    $calories = $_POST['calories'];
    $healthy_unhealthy = $_POST['healthy_unhealthy'];

    echo $food . $calories . $healthy_unhealthy;

    if (!empty($food) && !empty($calories) && !empty($healthy_unhealthy)) {
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO food (food, calories, healthy_unhealthy) VALUES (:food, :calories, :healthy)");
        $query->bindValue(':food', $food);
        $query->bindValue(':calories', $calories);
        $query->bindValue(':healthy', $healthy_unhealthy);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            echo '<br /><strong>Record Added!</strong><br />';
        } else {
            echo '<br />Oh no, there was a problem!<br />';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Please complete all fields.';
    }
}


?>

<form action="connect.php" method="POST">
    Food Type: <br />
    <input type="text" name="food"/><br /><br />
    Calories: <br />
    <input type="number" min="0" name="calories"/><br /><br />
    Healthy/Unhealthy? <br />
    <input type="radio" name="healthy_unhealthy" value="h"/>Healthy<br />
    <input type="radio" name="healthy_unhealthy" value="u"/>Unhealthy<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I thought it was to do with the fact that isset also checks for a null value, but in the example below it all works perfectly and I can't see the difference...

```
<?php

// Pilot Name, Currency Name, Currency Date, Interval (minutes)

if (isset($_POST['pilot']) && isset($_POST['currency']) && isset($_POST['last_date']) &&
        isset($_POST['interval'])) {
            $pilot = $_POST['pilot'];
            $currency = $_POST['currency'];
            $last_date = strtotime($_POST['last_date']);
            $interval = $_POST['interval'];

    if (!empty($pilot) && !empty($currency) && !empty($last_date) &&
            !empty($interval)) {

        echo 'Hello <strong>' . $pilot . '</strong>, your ' . $currency . ' is due on ' . date('d-m-y', $last_date + ($interval * 24 * 60 * 60)) .
            '<br />';
        echo 'Your last currency was ' . date('d-m-Y', $last_date) . '<br /><br />';

        } else {
            echo 'Please complete all fields.';
        }
}




?>

<form action="currency.php" method="POST">
    Enter your name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="pilot"/><br/>
    Enter the last date of your currency (dd-mm-yy):<br />
    <input type="date" name="last_date"/></br/>
    Enter the currency type:<br />
    <input type="text" name="currency"/><br/>
    Enter the currency interval in days: <br />
    <input type="text" name="interval"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Do you get in the first `if`? If not, apparently not all post data is present. Do you get any runtime errors? Do you see the proper values echoed? If you would echo anything right before inserting the record, do you see that echo?

Comment: What does happen when you leave a field empty? Do you get 'record added' , 'there was an error' , or a blank screen? ( php fatal error ). And if a fatal error , have you checked your log file?

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol if I receive no runtime errors. Everything works if the values are entered correctly, the record is added. If I don't enter any fields, or don't enter all fields it does nothing, just resets all the fields ready to go again. No fatal error. I tried echoing out under both isset and !empty and if I don't enter all fields it never enters those blocks.

Comment: Try `print_r( $_POST )` and the reason for the problem should become clear.

Comment: Hi everyone, I can confirm that @lejlot has the correct answer, it is the behaviour of the checkbox that is causing the first isset if block to fail every time. Thanks so much for everyone's help. Didn't think I deserved a downvote lol.

Comment: @nl-x Thanks for your help with a few of the responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you do not put any test in the input field, the submit button still sends data

```
<input name="sth" >
```

results in

```
$_POST['sth'] == ""
```

it is a variable, it is a string, it simply has length 0. You need more sophisticated testing of values then the `isset(.)` function. You can use `strlen(.)` (or `empty(.)`) for example.

This is not true for a checkbox, which does not behave as a traditional input, and it does not create a `$_POST['checkboxvalue']` value, which makes the first if statement - always `false`.

Comment: @nl-x Yes, but the problem is that the program execution never reaches that point because the first if evaluates to false.

Comment: Hi @lejlot this was the problem. Thanks very much. The behaviour of the checkbox was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're passing:

```
    if (isset($_POST['food']) && isset($_POST['calories']) && isset($_POST['healthy_unhealthy']))
```

Copy the else clause to that as well. To clarify, it's possible one of those fields is not set in the $_POST - common with checkboxes and radios.

Comment: This is theoretically correct, but it's not good practice to duplicate code.

Answer (score -1):

for healthy_unhealthy radio group, try the following check instead:

```
isset($_POST['healthy_unhealthy'])
```

Answer (score -1):

The first if condition also might be true when the second condition is true. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['food']) && isset($_POST['calories']) && isset($_POST['healthy_unhealthy'])) {
     $food = $_POST['food'];
     $calories = $_POST['calories'];
     $healthy_unhealthy = $_POST['healthy_unhealthy'];

    echo $food . $calories . $healthy_unhealthy;

    if (!empty($food) && !empty($calories) && !empty($healthy_unhealthy)) {
         ...
    } else {
        echo 'Please complete all fields.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Script parameters missing.';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Because condition in particular `if` statement always evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: lol thats almost a tautology .. he wants to know what is wrong

Comment: Well, a programmer who wants to know what goes wrong in their code, have to **debug** it. Not ask someone else to do it for him.

Comment: Yes but I dont think this will lead him to the solution ... anyways i didn't downvote .. just saying

Comment: Anyways, this kind of questions "I have a code but have no idea why doesn't it work" considered **too localized** here and thus not allowed. That's why I answered the only logical question were asked